# array of ByteArray into MemoryStream

Tags: c#, asp.net, multidimensional-array, arrays, memorystream

I have a method which returns a array of ByteArray:

```
public byte[][] Draw(ImageFormat imageFormat, ImageSize imageSize);
```

and I need to write it into a `MemoryStream`:

```
var byteArray = instanceName.Draw(ImageFormat.Jpeg, ImageSize.Dpi150);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray[0]);
```

This is working so far because the array of byteArray only ever has one element. Would someone be able to point out and provide a solution on : what would happen if the array of byteArray has more than one element?

I guess with current code I would still take the first element of the byteArray and discard the rest, but I need `MemoryStream` and it can not take a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iYou will have to loop and write, something like this:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
for(var i=0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
  ms.Write(byteArray[i], 0, byteArray[i].Length);
```

(I'm not sure it's working as-is, you might have to adjust it, but it's the principle)

Comment: This might not work as the second param in `Write` byte offset will not be the 0 for elements other than the first one. Good answer though.

Comment: Hm, no? It's the offset to begin writing from, not to.

Comment: you are right it is the byte offset in buffer at which to begin writing from. So this might just work as is then, no?

Comment: Probably, but I haven't tested it, so there might be compilation errors, or something similar :P

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned only the first element at [0] position would be used by memory stream. Since memory stream is sequential by design, you need a loop to flat your array of arrays and put it into memory stream.
As a second look to your code, I suggest to change your `Draw()` method to produce linear data structure rather than two dimensional (array of array) if you don't need this type of data structure anywhere else in your code.

Comment: I can't, this is from a third party control - I thought about that :)

Comment: Then write a wrapper class around it.

Comment: Ok, what if there is a reason that the third party control is returning an array of byteArray? Should we write a wrapper class just to change the return types of the original function?

Comment: It depends on how frequently you are going to flat a 2D memory model. If it's frequent, then I would write my wrapper class for encapsulating just ONE method.